# How to place image in tkinter(background) and place button on the image using python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Need to place buttons on image but image always stays on center and buttons stays on sides.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to give us more details, I am not sure what you want to do exactly. And please show us what you tried so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice.

Comment: I'm sure you'll find answers to most of your problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter?sort=frequent). (I've seem to have given wrong link on my comment earlier.)

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish that. You can achieve that with any of the normal geometry managers, `pack`, `place`, or `grid`. You need to do some research on these, try to come up with a solution, and then come back when you have a more specific question.

Comment: This can't be serious, how are we expected to help you with an issue when we have literally no idea what your code looks like? You're asking us a question relating to something that you haven't bothered to share. At the very least can you please provide a **minimal**, **complete** and **verifiable** example following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Why not place an image on a button instead? It's much easier :)

getting the buttons to have an image can be kind of tricky (you kind of need a 2 layered approach), but changing the image is easy.

```
x_image = 'x.png'

o_image = 'o.png'
```

then...

```
x_image_for_button = PhotoImage(file=x_image)
o_image_for_button = PhotoImage(file=o_image)
```

then.....

```
button = tk.Button(self.controller, image=o_image_for_button, command=lambda: command_or_something)
button.config(width="40", height="40")
button.place(x=5, y=5)
```

(add in self. or root. etc)

now all you do to change the image is:

```
button.set(image=o_image_for_button)
#on second thought... maybe use `button.config(image=o_image_for_button)` insted
```

easy :)